# how do I perform conditial query params in axios?

Tags: reactjs, rest, endpoint

I am trying to build a conditional dynamic react component where makes an API call based on the user interaction, but if the user types something in the search bar. I want to add `search=` param the otherwise use `/list` endpoint without query params. I am using currently Axios , and I would like to know some approach to do the following

```
const FeedsList = () => {
    const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
    const [currentPageUrl, setCurrentPageUrl] = useState("http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/")
  

    const performSearch = () =>  {
      //setLoading(true)
      api.get(currentPageUrl).then(res => { // axios call 
        setLoading(false)
        setFeed(res.data.results)
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  
    const handleSearch = (e) =>{
      console.log(e.target.value)
      //performSearch();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        performSearch()
      }, [currentPageUrl]);
    
      if (loading) return "Loading..."
    }


export const api = axios.create(
    {baseURL : 'http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/'}
    )
```

user input

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter  keyword" onChange={event => handleSearch(event)}/>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code handling user input?

Comment: @Nick upated, I forgot the user input

Comment: is the `input` element rendered by a parent element? If so, then this needs to be handled there

Answer (score 0):

Store user input to state, not URL, and then  construct your URL from initial value (list) and user input, if any:

```js
const FeedsList = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");

  const performSearch = (searchString) => {
    setLoading(true);
    let url = "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/feeds/list/";
    // you might want to escape this value, and sanitize input on the server
    if (searchString) url = `${url}?search=${searchString}`;
    const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    return api
      .get(url, { cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token })
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setFeed(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    return cancelTokenSource;
  };

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchString(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let token = performSearch(searchString);
    return () => token.cancel();
  }, [searchString]);

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
};
```

You might want to debounce or throttle requests, so you will not bombard your server with requests on each keystroke

Comment: what is `setState` built in function?

Comment: I edited code already. It should be `setSearchString`

Comment: And added missing parameter in `performSearch` call inside `useEffect`

Comment: sure . do you mean by `debounce or throttle requests` by limiting to 100 per minute or debounce approach

Comment: Right now new request will be fired on each (or almost each) keystroke. It is not very good, and can make UI unersponsive. With debounce your function will run after small delay after user stopped typing. With throttlle requests will fire not more often than once in specific time. Here you can read more about this techniques: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Answer (score 0):

The Axios api allows for passing a second parameter to the `get` method which is the config for the request being sent. That `config` object takes a `params` property that would be parsed and appended onto the url as a query string. The nice thing is if the params object is empty it will be like not passing anything at all. A fuller example [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) on their GitHub page.

Passing an empty params object is the same as passing no params object at all in terms of what is requested.

```
// both lines request url looks like this => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', { params: {} })
```

To answer your question you could conditionally just create the params based on whether there is a value from the search input, something like the following:

```js
    const performSearch = () =>  {
        const config = search === '' ? { 
            params: {} 
        } : { 
            params: { search } // same as { search: search }
        }
        
        api.get(currentPageUrl, config).then(res => { 
            // do something with response
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

An assumption in the above would be that you stored the `search` value in state somewhere and add it to your `useEffect` dependencies list, referencing it in `performSearch`.